# Catch MemoryStream object in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I am returning a Memory stream object  from my active x control which i want to receive the returned memory strem object  in my javascript function.

If it returns string, i am getting the return string in var str , but how we do it for memory stream.

Please suggent any example or code.

Thanks

Comment: If you do something like "var result = ActiveX.DoWork()" and the result is a stream what is the variable set to?